# Write to a local file using Android WebView and JS

Tags: javascript, android

I am working on an android app that should write to a local file on device. A simple txt file. But i want to do this via the web view + javascript feature. In my activity I have a button which points to a URL. When user taps it, it requests a json file. I want to write this blob to disk in the javascript part of the app itself. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by the javascript part. If you are in an Android app, you should have access to a Context. If you have any Context, you can do IO:

```
private String read(String fn)
{
    try {
        FileInputStream mInput = {{CONTEXT}}.openFileInput(fn);
        byte[] data = new byte[128];
        mInput.read(data);
        mInput.close();
        String display = new String(data);
        return display.trim();
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ERROR;
    }
}

private void write(String fn, String data)
{
    try {
        FileOutputStream mOutput = {{CONTEXT}}.openFileOutput(fn);
        mOutput.write(data.getBytes());
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but i do not want to use that for writing to a file. Basically i want to use javascript calls to write to a file. So you are saying that i call the above functions (or similar) using JS ?